# Rasa - Docker Permission denied: 'models/20200427-162547.tar.gz'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa-nlu, rasa

I'm trying to user docker with Rasa from image `rasa/rasa:1.8.1-full`

I have the following `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:1.8.1-full
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: 
      - run
      - --cors
      - "*"
      - --enable-api
    depends_on:
      - actions

... more services ...
```

So far so good,I can run a `docker-compose up` and both services will be up and running, however, when I connect to `rasa` service to train it by `docker-compose exec rasa /bin/bash`, the user 1001 has no write permission.

Since I do not want to keep my own dockerfile/image in this case, and by default the official rasa image uses the user 1001, I don't know what I can do about it.

Should I pass the trained file already to the container? The machine who will host the container will not have Rasa installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create your own Docker image starting from `rasa:1.8.1-full`: in your Dockerfile you can then add the files that rasa needs (model, domain, stories, etc..).
The result will be an image including Rasa runtime and the model you train/test locally, which can run on any Docker environment (no need to worry about Rasa being available as it will be included in your image).

As you train new models (and change the stories) you can repackage and redeploy,

Comment: So each time I train the model, I would generate a new build of this image?

Comment: Yes, thats what I do: I train and test locally so end up creating the image once I am ready, and re-packaging if there is some fix or evolution. I find it ok (because locally I dont need to). If you need to change the model very often (while the app is running) then you might want to to look into the API and how to push a model in at runtime

Answer (score 1):

use this \

> $ sudo chgrp -R root models && sudo chmod -R 770 models
> $ sudo chgrp -R root . && sudo chmod -R 770 .

Comment: Could you add some explanation in your anwser please.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

1. sudo su
2. sudo chgrp -R root /etc/rasa/models && sudo chmod -R 770 /etc/rasa/models

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if our problems were the same.
But I was using a `docker-compose` file with train e run services from rasa.

I had the same problem with this `Permission denied models` and I solved this with `user: root` in rasa train service in docker-compose.yml.

```yaml
version: '3.0'
services:
  rasa-train:
    image: rasa/rasa:2.2.5-full
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:
      - train 
  rasa-run:
    image: rasa/rasa:2.2.5-full
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:
      - run 
      - --cors 
      - "*"
```